# How to position Vue md-dialog based on element or event property (without using x,y coordinates)

Tags: vue-material

When clicked on a button, I want to position the Vue material dialog under the button.The button is inside nested iframes. So, the x,y coordinates of button does not match the viewport coordinate.
Is there a way to position a Vue md-dialog relative to an element. I cannot use x and y coordinates using css as there are too many iframes and calculation of the exact x,y coordinate is difficult, even with element.getBoundingClientRect().

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that md-dialog css places the dialog box in the center of the screen using css translate. Once it was overridden, it was easy to solve the issue.

> .md-dialog{
>           -webkit-transform: translate(0%,0%);
>           transform: translate(0%,0%);
>       }